# Laravel: How to see if user is logged in in Base Controller?

Tags: laravel-6

I want to be able to change a field called "last_accessed" in the users table on each and every request the user makes.

I have a controller called "ContentController" which extends "Controller". So I figured just adding code in the constructor of "Controller":

```
public function __construct()
{
  $user = \Auth::user();
  if (Auth::check()) {
    print 'Good';
  }
  else print "Bad";
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't it to see that I'm authorized.

Can someone please tell me:

1. Why is AUTH not working in the base controller?
2. How can I update the last_accessed field upon each view if this controller idea of mine isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that doesn't work in `__construct()`. There is a workaround. It works but I'm not sure if some other Laravel users will accept my answer. What you should do is create a middleware and work from there. You can use an anonymous function, which in this case, mimics a middleware:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $user = $request->user();
        if ($user) {
            print 'Good';
        }
        else print "Bad";

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

If no user is logged in, `$user` will be `null`.

Comment: It works, but it also seems "wrong" to me. Is there perhaps a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes. With MiddleWare. You can activate any MiddleWare in the Route request. There was some time ago a long discussion on the GitHub Laravel/framework about this issue. It's a bit of a grey area. Although this solution works, some have warned this solution could stop working on later (major) Laravel upgrades (^6.0 to ^7.0 for example). As with ^7.0 nothing really changed in the MiddleWare functionality. In other words, this solution still stands for the latest Laravel version.